# How to use RegExp to match all characters between HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want to use JavaScript to match ALL content between `<div class="class-test">` and  `</div>`. What RegExp should I use?

The complicated part is, there might be some more HTML tags inside it. For example:

```
<div class="class-test">
  <div> this is a sub div </div>
  <p>this is a p</p>
</div>
```

BTW, The HTML is not real HTML but just pure text. So it's not possible to 'parse' it. I am actually using Node.JS to modify a HTML file.

Thanks.

Comment: Seriously, you're in JavaScript, you have a DOM *right there*! Just dump it into a `div` and get its `textContent`.

Comment: Or `innerText` (older versions of IE), and which `</div>`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with a module like [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cheerio):

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var $ = cheerio.load('<div class="class-test"><div> this is a sub div </div><p>this is a p</p></div>');

var content = $('div.class-test').html();
console.log(content);
```

Comment: ... really? You couldn't just... I dunno, use `var d = document.createElement('div'); d.innerHTML = html; alert(d.textContent || d.innerText);`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol OP uses Node.js.

Comment: Welp. Would've been nice if the right tag were on the question...